# SunMSCAPI not recognizing private keys for some keystore entries

Tags: java, security, authentication, ssl, mscapi

I apologize that this is so long.  If you are familiar with doing client-auth in Java you can probably skim/skip to the bottom.  I took me a long time to find all the relevant bits of information from disparate sources.  Maybe this will help someone else.

I'm working on a proof-of-concept to get client-side authentication working from a Java client using the Windows keystore.  I have a servlet that I have created that can request or require client certificates.  It simply returns an HTML response containing the certificate information including subject DN and the serial number.  I've worked through a number of experiments with browsers (mainly Chrome and IE) to verify it is working.  I've gotten successful client authentication working with both certs I've generated with SSL and also using certs issued by my companies internal CA.

My next step is to have a Java client that works with the MSCAPI keystore in Java.  The reason I went this route is that the certificates we want to use are issued by our internal CA and are automatically added to the Personal keystore in Windows and are marked as non-exportable.  I know there are ways to get the private key out of the keystore with some free tools if you are an admin on your workstation.  This isn't a viable option in this case for various reasons.  Here's the code I ended up with:

```
private static SSLSocketFactory getFactory() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException 
{
  KeyStore roots = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT", new SunMSCAPI());
  KeyStore personal = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", new SunMSCAPI());

  roots.load(null,null);
  personal.load(null,null);

  TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
  tmf.init(roots);

  KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
  kmf.init(personal, "".toCharArray());

  SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

  context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

  return context.getSocketFactory();
}
```

This works but when I connect, the Java client is authenticating with the client-certs I had previously generated.  I don't see an obvious way to force the selection of a specific key so I figured it was just picking the first key it came across that the host trusts.  I then removed these certs that I had created from the windows keystore and it would no longer authenticate.  I triple-checked that the server-side was still works with the browsers and it does.  I then readded these certs to the personal keystore and removed the trust of my pseudo-CA from the server-side.  Still works in the browser and not in the client.

I added -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake to my VM parameters and started looking through the output.  One thing I see is are lines "found key for : [alias]" for each of the certs that I have added but not for the ones added through the 'self-enrollment' feature of certmgr.msc.  Initially I thought it was because they were exportable but I removed them and added one back as non-exportable and java can still use it.  I'm at a loss as to why SunMSCAPI won't use these certs.  Both the ones created by me and internal CA are sha256RSA.  Both are enabled for client authentication.  When I add the following code, I see that isKeyEntry() is false for all the key-pairs I want to use:

```
Enumeration<String> aliases = personal.aliases();

while (aliases.hasMoreElements())
{
  String alias = aliases.nextElement();

  System.out.println(alias + " " + personal.isKeyEntry(alias));
}
```

I found someone else with a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652206/some-certificates-private-keys-in-windows-my-not-detected) but no definitive answer.